# C++ Store an expression template inside a class whose objects will be part of a vector

Tags: c++, expression, stdvector

[Extensively edited for clarity and typos, and now with attempted solution, old version at the end]

**New version of the question**

I have a class which needs to store a functor. The problem is that the functor is an expression template (meaning that each functor is of different type). On top of that I need to collect all the objects of that class in a vector.

Below my attempts:

I do not write the code for the functors as expression templates as it is too long. I will therefore test the code by trying to store two functors of two different classes

```
struct FunctorTypeA {
    double a;
    FunctorTypeA(const double ap): a(ap) {}
    double operator()(const double x){ return a;}
};

struct FunctorTypeB {
    double a, b;
    FunctorTypeB(const double ap, const double bp): a(ap), b(bp) {}
    double operator()(const double x){ return a+b*x;}
};
```

I think, correct me if I am wrong, that if the code below works for the two functors above, it should work for any functor constructed with expression templates.

The first idea would be

```
template <typename functorType> struct myClass {
    functorType    functor;
    myClass(functorType funct): functor(funct){}
};
```

I can store a functor inside an object of that class with:

```
FunctorTypeA functor1(1.2);
FunctorTypeB functor2(1.5, 5.0);
myClass      myObj1(functor1);
myClass      myObj2(functor2);
cout << myObj1.functor(0.2) << " " << myObj1.functor(0.2) << "\n\n";
```

However I cannot store those objects in an `std::vector` as they have different types.

Therefore I tried:

```
struct myClass2Base {
    virtual ~TrialClassBase() = default;
    virtual double functor(const double x) = 0;
};

template <typename functorType> struct myClass2 : public myClass2Base {
    functorType    functorStored;
    myClass2(functorType funct): functorStored(funct){}
    double functor(const double x){return functorStored(x);}
};
```

and I can construct a vector of those objects as

```
std::vector<myClass2Base*> vecOfObj;
vecOfObj.push_back(new myClass2(functor1));
    
cout << vecOfObj[0]->functor(0.3) << "\n\n";
```

This one works.
Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

**Old version of the question**

I have a class which needs to store a functor which is an expression template (meaning that each function is of different type). I also need to put the objects of that class in an std::vector.

My Attempt is

```
struct TrialClassBase{
    virtual double get_functor(double) = 0;
};

template <typename derived> struct TrialClass : public TrialClassBase {
    derived functor;
    TrialClass(derived fun): functor(fun){}
    double get_functor(double x) {return functor(x);}
};

std::vector<shared_ptr<TrialClassBase>> vecOfObjs;
```

Then I try to add an object to the vector. As an example I use an std::function, only as an example: the functor in my case will be an expression template.

```
std::function<double(double)>  funcccc = [](double x){return x*x;};
vecc.emplace_back(TrialClass(funcccc));
cout << vecc[0]->get_functor(0.3) <<"\n\n";
```

This fails to compile. What mistake am I making? How can I do what I want to do?

Thanks!

Comment: do you really need a `shared_ptr`? Often people don't and a `unique_ptr` will be enough.

Comment: Please provide [mcve], you can use this as starting point: https://godbolt.org/z/qhW5v5fda

Comment: I almost finished writing an answer explaining the two fundamental defects in the shown code, but then I realized that the shown code is completely fake. The first code snippet declares a vector named `vecOfObjs`. The second code snippet then references some other mysterious object named `vecc`. Who knows what the real code looks like, and I realized that any answer will be mere speculation, because the real code is likely to be completely different from the shown code.

Comment: Have you considered `std::vector<std::function<double(double)>>`? That way the standard library does the type-erasure for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have improved your question.
Yes there are debatably better solutions.

One nice solution the std lib offers you, is to use type-erasure using [`std:function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct FunctorTypeA {
    double a;
    FunctorTypeA(const double ap): a(ap) {}
    auto operator()([[maybe_unused]]const double x) const { return a;}
};


int main(){
    auto funcVec{std::vector<std::function<double(double)>>{}};
    funcVec.push_back(FunctorTypeA{3.14}); // functor allowed
    funcVec.push_back([](double x){return x;}); // lambda allowed
    funcVec.push_back(sqrt); // function pointer allowed, e.g. C math function

    for(auto&& f:funcVec){
        std::cout << f(2.0) << '\n';
    }
}
```

This way you don't complicate things with inheritance and pointer casting. Easy to make mistakes there. `std::vector` and `std::function` will do all the cleaning up. (That was something you can easily miss in your vector-of-pointers solution)

Note: `std::function` may perform a dynamic allocation. But so does `std::vector` and inheritance has vtable overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Your construction of the `shared_ptr` is invalid

As pointed in the comments:

- A base class should always have a virtual destructor
- `push_back` is to be preferred

```cpp
struct TrialClassBase {
  virtual double get_functor(double) = 0;
  virtual ~TrialClassBase() = default;
};

template <typename derived> struct TrialClass : public TrialClassBase {
  derived functor;
  TrialClass(derived fun) : functor(fun) {
  }
  double get_functor(double x) {
    return functor(x);
  }
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TrialClassBase>> vecc;

int main() {
  std::function<double(double)> funcccc = [](double x) { return x * x; };
  vecc.push_back(
    std::make_shared<TrialClass<std::function<double(double)>>>(funcccc));
  std::cout << vecc[0]->get_functor(0.3) << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Two things: 1) memory leak. The base class doesn't have a virtual destructor. 2) emplace_back should be push_back, as make_shared instantiates the object.

Comment: I agree that both of them are best practices, but 1) there is no memory leak since there is no memory allocation in the derived class and a `shared_ptr` can be copied - but you are right and I am updating my answer

Comment: `std::function` definitely can do a memory allocation. You can even write a custom allocator for it. I think it has some small object optimization, but there are plenty cases where it will allocate. Anyhow. IMHO this a bad use-case for `shared_ptr`, and it should be a `unique_ptr`.